# Creating random URLs in Django

Tags: python, django, frameworks

I'm working on a project, I want to code the following steps

=> The user in **page A** wants to access to **page B**, so the user in **page A** will redirect to **page B** after validating the form,  then :

1. Creating a random url
2. The user is redirected to that random URL
3. the user cant access to **page B** if he doesn't validate the form on **page A**

I use **django 2.1**

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please complete your [tour] and see [ask].  Please note StackOverflow is not a coding service, but if you have made an attempt in implementing what you want, and have issues with that attempt, please [edit] your question to provide your code as a [MCVE] to increase the chance of your receiving help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `reverse` from `django.url` and can able to pass random `args` or `kwargs`  [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urlresolvers/).

Say your urls are be like

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('articles/', your_article_view),
    path('articles/<slug:slug>/', your_article_slug_view),
]
```

and from your `article_view` you can redirect to `article_slug_view` as

```
reverse('articles', args=['hello'])
'/articles/hello' # url
```

you can generate `uuid` and pass it by this, this will always make sure random different url everytime. Whatever you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let me say that this looks like an anti-pattern.

On Django you can set url's that matches some expression:

```
path('secret/<slug:passwd>/', views.super_secret, name="secret")
```

Then, you can redirect to this url with a key:

```
if form.is_valid():
    some_key = #some random key
    cache.set(some_key, True, 3)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('secret', args=(some_key,)))
```

And check your key from cache on view `secret`.